# 2D game engines for Android with web service support

Tags: java, android, web-services, coronasdk, stencyl

I need to create an Android application with lots of graphics and many rather complex calculations.

I want to do the calculations on a server and use the Android app only for interacting with the user (receiving user input, graphics).

I'm thinking about using Stencyl or Corona SDK for implementing the client.

If I implement the Android client with Stencyl or Corona, will I be able to communicate with a server via a web service?

Comment: Corona SDK can do network communication, but Web Service part has to write your own logic, no native support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this on Corona using Network Request see this [link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html)